# Find where one condition exists, but is empty or has no value for the other condition?

Tags: sql-server

I have item numbers that have different price list  codes. I am trying to find all items that have a price list code of '01' but do not have a 'ma' for that same item number. I have tried this code, but these items have both codes '01' and 'ma'. I am looking for items numbers with code '01' that do not have a 'ma' code.

The picture shows that the same item number appears in both '01' and 'MA' price lists

```
SELECT
    [Country_IBS]
    , [Item_Number]
    , [Price_List]
    , [Sales_Price]
    , [Currency]    
FROM [DATA_IBS].[dbo].[fact_List_Prices_ALL_ALL_COUNTRIES]
where Price_List in ('01')
and Price_List not in ('ma')
```

[image]

Comment: Use `where exists(...) and not exists(...)` - most natural way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot of data:

```
WITH MAPrice AS
(
SELECT      [Item_Number]
FROM        [DATA_IBS].[dbo].[fact_List_Prices_ALL_ALL_COUNTRIES]
WHERE       Price_List != 'MA'
GROUP BY    [Item_Number]
)
SELECT  c.[Country_IBS]
,       c.[Item_Number]
,       c.[Price_List]
,       c.[Sales_Price]
,       c.[Currency]
FROM    [DATA_IBS].[dbo].[fact_List_Prices_ALL_ALL_COUNTRIES] c
JOIN    MAPrice p ON p.[Item_Number] = c.[Item_Number]
WHERE   c.Price_List = '01'
```

Comment: The LIKE function wouldn't work in this scenario as there are other records with a Price List Code that contains '01' within it. This still includes Price List Codes with 'ma'

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot sample then of your data to better help?

Comment: Edited based on you screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Country_IBS],M.[Item_Number],[Price_List],[Sales_Price],[Currency] 
FROM 
[DATA_IBS].[dbo].[fact_List_Prices_ALL_ALL_COUNTRIES] M
INNER JOIN (SELECT [Item_Number] FROM [DATA_IBS]. 
[dbo].[fact_List_Prices_ALL_ALL_COUNTRIES] 
WHERE Price_List ='ma'  
Group BY [Item_Number])S ON S.Item_Number<>M.Item_Number
WHERE Price_List='01'
```

You can use `SUB Query` to attain this

Comment: Can u share any Table with Data details to help u further? - @phew

Comment: I added a picture showing that the same item number appears in both the '01' and 'MA' price lists